# ConnectionError Handling in Async HTTP requests with Python

Tags: python, python-requests, gevent, pool, connectionexception

Provided main goal is to make the script run(without **blocking**/ **interrupting other tasks** when a **ConnectionError** is raised) anyway even if there is a temporary absence of the Internet connection.

While I was implementing error handling in my script for sending asynchronous **HTTP** requests, I came across a weird behavior when the **ConnectionError** exception is raised:

*It's as if the Internet connection is absent, **greenlet** blocks coccurrency of requests, and just a single request is made at time, loosing the simultaneity of tasks.*

Here is an example that I hope makes everything clear:

```
#Python 3.4 Windows 7 64 bit
import gevent.monkey
gevent.monkey.patch_all()
from gevent.pool import Pool
import requests
import time
import os

url = "http://pythonrequest.altervista.org/ten_seconds_delayed.php"
def task(args):
    try:
        r = requests.get(url)
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as e:
        print("[ERROR]: ", e)

pool = Pool(10)
start_time = time.time()
for i in range(0,10):
    args = []
    args.append(i)
    args.append(url)
    pool.spawn(task, args)

print("Tasks sent to the pool, waiting for completing...")
pool.join()
end_time = time.time()
seconds_elapsed = end_time-start_time
print("Tasks completed")
print("seconds_elapsed: ",seconds_elapsed)
os.system("PAUSE")
```

I ran the script two times in two conditions.

First time I ran the script with a working internet connection.
Execution time is about **10 seconds**.
Second time, I ran the script with an absent internet connection(Windows->Devices->Net Device->Disable).
Execution time comes to **100 seconds** around. 
Why 100 seconds? Shouldn' t be 10 seconds since the timeout for a single request is 10 seconds?
It seems the execution time is timeout_of_request*number_of_request.
I'm excpeting that in the second case, the execution time is *timeout_of_request*.
If the requests were simultaneous they should take 10 seconds around to complete, otherwise it means they are not simultaneous?
What I need is to preserve the simultaneity of tasks. Any suggestion?

Comment: Don't you have to monkey patch before your other imports, especially 'requests'?

Comment: I did as you suggested(I also fixed code in Question), but It seems that the problem persists.